# Real Analysis (Proof)

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm thinking that maybe this is an application of the Mean Value Theorem. But I'm not sure how to do it. Please help. >.<

i) Let $a>0$ and $n>2$.
If $$\frac{a}{1+2a}< \frac{1}{n}$$ ,  prove that $$a<\frac{1}{n-2}$$ .

ii) Let $f$ be a positive function on $\mathbb{R} $. 
If $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{1+2f(x)} = 0 $$,
prove that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x) = 0 $$ .

Comment: (i) is not MVT, it is straight algebraic manipulation.  And (ii) follows from (i).

Comment: Can you please show me how to prove it algebraically for (i)?

Comment: It has been done in detail by Jennifer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $1+2a>0$ and $n>0$, so :

$$\frac{a}{1+2a}< \frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow a<\frac{1+2a}{n}\Rightarrow na<1+2a\Rightarrow (n-2)a<1$$
But $n>2$, so $n-2 >0$ and :
$$(n-2)a<1\Rightarrow a<\frac {1}{n-2}$$

For the second question, with the first result you have $\forall n>2,\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{1+2f(x)} = 0<\frac{1}{n}$.
Also $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{1+2f(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)}{1+2(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x))}$$ So with the first question you have :
$$\forall n>2,\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)<\frac{1}{n-2}$$

So $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x) \le 0$ and $f$ is a positive function so $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)\geq 0$. Finally $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete solution, Jennifer.

Comment: May I know why $$\forall n>2,\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)<\frac{1}{n-2}$$ implies $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x) \le 0$ ??

Comment: $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists n$ such that $\frac{1}{n-2}<\epsilon$. So $\forall \epsilon >0,\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)< \epsilon$. So it means that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x) \le 0$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: because $a$ and $n$ are positive then you can pass the factors from one side of the inequality to the other and the inequality holds.

Then you can simplify the fraction.

If $f$ is a positive function remember that $\lim f(x)=\frac{1}{\lim f(x)^{-1}}$